# Cookies not persisting with internet explorer but do with Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cookies

We have two servers with exactly the same code on them (production & test). We have built a central login that (after login) takes the user to a list of applications that they have permission to access. On production, this works perfectly, regardless of the browser used. On our test server, with exactly the same code, we have problems with the cookies setting in ie (but not Chrome).

In production, after login, the console will show a request cookie and a response cookie:

**Request Cookies**

```
_RequestVerificationToken_L0xheW9mZg2: RhXY0_65bMeMZra7sQlwRMJoUuSG0f5LMybgd62OwzX1swkP1SHUT6ZrcIGrJTT0o0yhSUGwESnGkTHuDyKDRfwQIwWOf3RigZzfjBiv5YA1

ASP.NET_SessionId: tgovhdz0udw2bordzjcr2z5s
```

**Response Cookies**

```
%3F1%20QwvkvhRKMxl3E1Nv9lUfgw%3D%3D:%3F1%20LP33ZKJCkSLzfdpaiDunsA%3D%3D
expires: Fri, 24-Mar-2017 18:34:13 GMT
HttpOnly: true
path: /
secure: true
```

On the test server, it shows two Response Cookies and no Request Cookies:

**Request Cookies**

**Response Cookies**

```
%3F1%20QwvkvhRKMxl3E1Nv9lUfgw%3D%3D:%3F1%20WW4g1Ey6zMpuKAUXE3sgnQ%3D%3D
expires: Fri, 24-Mar-2017 18:36:38 GMT
HttpOnly: true
path: /
secure: true

ASP.NET_SessionId: ge02n3nmyhsigazrgzhszpou
HttpOnly: true
path: /
secure: true
```

The settings in IIS appear to be the same on both servers, but we must be missing something. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After days of searching (and 45 minutes after asking this question), I've found the answer: our domain name for our test server is prefaced with "test_". This is a violation of the RDC (only letters, numbers and hyphens are allowed), and Internet Explorer (and Edge) drop the cookies when this occurs (even though chrome still works fine).